# converting a PIL image to wxPython bitmap image

Tags: python, bitmap, wxpython, python-imaging-library

I can load a JPEG image, convert it to bitmap and plot it in a wx application. I am having however a hard time in converting a PIL image object into a bitmap that can be plotted into a wx application.

Online, the best suggestion I could find is to do something like

```
wx.Bitmap(PIL_image.tobytes())
```

However, this gives me the following error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 59: invalid start byte
```

or

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 51: invalid continuation byte
```

Has someone a good hint on how to address this point? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are examples all over the internet on how to do it. But there are some conditions which aren't covered in them.
Especially when converting wxBitmap() back to PIL Image().

I post here my modified versions of these functions. Conversion is fast and reliable.

```
from PIL import Image
import wx

def PIL2wx (image):
    width, height = image.size
    return wx.BitmapFromBuffer(width, height, image.tobytes())

def wx2PIL (bitmap):
    size = tuple(bitmap.GetSize())
    try:
        buf = size[0]*size[1]*3*"\x00"
        bitmap.CopyToBuffer(buf)
    except:
        del buf
        buf = bitmap.ConvertToImage().GetData()
    return Image.frombuffer("RGB", size, buf, "raw", "RGB", 0, 1)


# Suggested usage is to put the code in a separate file called
# helpers.py and use it as this:

from helpers import wx2PIL, PIL2wx
from PIL import Image

i = Image.open("someimage.jpg").convert("RGB")
wxb = PIL2wx(i)
# Now draw wxb to screen and let user draw something over it using wxDC() and so on...
# Then pick a wx.Bitmap() from wx.DC() and do something like:
wx2PIL(thedc.GetAsBitmap()).save("some new image.jpg")
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but I had to modify it like this:                                      `return wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, image.convert("RGB").tobytes())`

Comment: Are you sure that you had to add an extra  dot between Bitmap and FromBuffer? Just to confirm it. Because if you did then there are some changes introduced in newer versions of wxPython of which I am not aware yet. As for convert(), well, sorry I forgot to return it. I removed it because my current application works with RGB by default, so there is no need for extra convert(). If it is present it only makes the function widely usable, but it slows it down in other cases. I am using PIL to prepare an image from camera and then I draw it on wx.Panel(). So every usec is precious.

Comment: Yes, there have been changes. Without the dot you get just a warning for now. About the RGB conversion, I understand. I just commented on it as it might be useful for other people reading your answer.